# How do I get the querystring for a GET form, just BEFORE submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with `method="get"`  When someone clicks submit, I'd like to querystring that is automatically appended to the form `action` before it submits.

i.e., I'm trying to open a get form in a jQuery modal with `.load`...

`$("#myform").attr("action")` is the literal action attribute, not the URL that's about to be `GET`ted... :)

I'd like jQuery or JavaScript, and I'm hoping I don't need a plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for this.

```
var fullurl = $("#myform").attr("action") + "?" + $("#myform").serialize();
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!  I"ll mark as answered... in 11 minutes... :)  you were fast

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#myform` is the ID of the form in question, you can get the query string of any form by calling `$.serialize()`, regardless of the action attribute.

On this page, for example, you can open up a debugger and call the following:

```
> $('#post-form').serialize()
"qualityBanWarningShown=false&post-text=Assuming+%60%23myform%60+is+the+ID+of+the+form+in+question%2C+you+can+get+the+query+string+of+any+form+by+calling+%60%24.serialize()%60.+On+this+page%2C+for+example%2C+you+can+open+up+a+debugger.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%24('%23post-form').serialize()&fkey=nope&author=&i1l=nopenope"
```